# How to change current branch in git from master to main

Tags: git

It is common to change main branches from the old pattern `master` to `main`. This can be easily done remotely (GitHub offers a graphical way to do it), but... what should be done with working copies?

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. rename your local branch:

   ```
   git branch -m master main
   ```
2. change the tracked branch

   ```
   git fetch -p origin
   git branch -u origin/main main
   ```
3. change the main local branch

   ```
   git remote set-head origin -a
   ```
4. optionally, remove the master branch, local and remotely:

   ```
   git branch -D master
   git push origin :master
   ```

**Updates**

- added the `-p` parameter in step 2, thanks to @torek.
- add the optional step to remove the master branch

Comment: I might recommend `git fetch -p origin` or setting `fetch.prune` to `true` during step 2, but this is the sequence you want, yes.

Comment: I found that editing HEAD in the remote repo (if you have ssh access) changes the default branch, so in myrepo/HEAD (if it is a bare repo) change ref: refs/heads/master to ref: refs/heads/main then by default main is used when the repository is cloned.

Comment: This doesn't work unless you already have a main branch on the remote origin, so it is correct for the question, but doesn't apply for scenarios where the name change is initiated on local.

Answer (score 2):

```
git branch --unset-upstream
```

After

```
git branch -m master main
```

Otherwise, I would get the following error:

`fatal: the requested upstream branch 'origin/main' does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

I had to use

`git branch -u origin/**master** main`

instead of the

`git branch -u origin/main main`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and least error-prone way:

1. rename remote repo branch using GitHub web interface,
2. move local repo folder to `/tmp`,
3. `git clone` remote repo.

---

Note: this assumes you start when local repo is in sync with remote one, which you may want to verify first (by pushing or pulling). If after the fact you find you lost some local changes, you can restore them to your local repo from the backup made in step 2) and commit / push them.